# Is it possible to select one column based on another column without using subquery in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, timescaledb, hypertable

I'm working in a TimescaleDB in PostgreSQL. I have the following table:

```
| id |      timestamp      |
----------------------------
| 1  | 2021-07-12 01:04:58 |
| 2  | 2021-07-12 02:12:03 |
| 3  | 2021-07-12 04:44:11 |
| 4  | 2021-07-12 05:08:31 |
```

Can I select the time in one hour buckets with timestamp as timestamp_start and timestamp plus one hour as timestamp_end, in one query (meaning no sub query)?

So this is the result I'm looking for:

```
|   timestamp_start   |    timestamp_end    |
---------------------------------------------
| 2021-07-12 01:00:00 | 2021-07-12 02:00:00 |
| 2021-07-12 02:00:00 | 2021-07-12 03:00:00 |
| 2021-07-12 03:00:00 | 2021-07-12 04:00:00 |
| 2021-07-12 04:00:00 | 2021-07-12 05:00:00 |
| 2021-07-12 05:00:00 | 2021-07-12 06:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `date_trunc`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour',tm) AS timstamp_start, 
  date_trunc('hour',tm) + interval '1 hour' AS timstamp_end
FROM t;

   timstamp_start    |    timstamp_end     
---------------------+---------------------
 2021-07-12 01:00:00 | 2021-07-12 02:00:00
 2021-07-12 02:00:00 | 2021-07-12 03:00:00
 2021-07-12 04:00:00 | 2021-07-12 05:00:00
 2021-07-12 05:00:00 | 2021-07-12 06:00:00
(4 rows)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb47796cb9b0224c778e672cd11602fe)

Comment: Is it not possible with the time_bucket function?

Comment: HI@Ben, the documentation claims that `time_bucket` is a way more powerful and easier than `date_trunc` (although I can hardly see how it can get easier than that), so I cannot imagine it is not possible. In my example I just wanted to illustrate how easy it is with pure standard postgres.

Comment: @JimJones right, and that claim is just wrong. time-bucket is not more powerful - it doesn't even work for months, etc.: see: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/414#issuecomment-455556569

Answer (score 0):

It works, you can declare the same as `date_trunc`:

```sql
tsdb=> select time_bucket('1 hour', time) as start, time_bucket('1 hour', time) + interval '1 hour' as end_date from conditions limit 1;
┌────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│         start          │        end_date        │
├────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ 2010-01-06 22:00:00+00 │ 2010-01-06 23:00:00+00 │
└────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```